# Python/Google Apps Script integration

Tags: python, google-apps-script

Would it be possible for some type of Python script to check services running on a linux box, and integrate with a google app script, so it would then populate a google doc spreadsheet stating whther a service is running or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You would need to authorize it the first time and implement oAuth from the script though. I strongly suggest that you switch to the Google Drive API.

Comment: thanks for the reply Luke... Do you know of any examples of code out there, i could possibly look at amending/modify to give myself an understanding , so i can implement ?